# Android Studio exporting APK error Android resource linking failed

Tags: android

Hi this is the first time I am asking a question on any type of forum but i have look everywhere and no one has a answer or even this type of question.

I developed a game in Buildbox and then exported android. Then I imported into android studio(keep in mind i have a google console account and my end goal is to upload the game to the google play store) in buildbox i went to the settings and set the bundle ID(com.companyname.appname) to what my ID is.

Now when i try to export generated signed APK from android studio i get a error Android resource linking failed. what i did notice is when i leave out the bundle ID the export works fine but then google wont allow me to upload.

How do I get this to work?

Comment: Does the error say what resource is missing? Could be a missing dependency of some sort. A screenshot of the error message may be helpful

Comment: Android resource linking failed
D:\APK GAmes\2DDash\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:2: error: attribute 'package' in <manifest> tag is not a valid Android package name: 'com.RAIndustry.2DDash'.
D:\APK GAmes\2DDash\android\app\build\intermediates\merged_manifests\release\AndroidManifest.xml:63: error: attribute 'android:name' in <activity> tag must be a valid Java class name.

Comment: That is the error in the error message box

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From reading the error statement, I am sure there are some issues in your AndroidManifest.xml

line 2 has inappropriate package name `com.RAIndustry.2DDash` try changing this to `com.raindustry.dash2d`. The `2DDash` becomes the name of the directly on the file system. Some OS dont allow starting a directory name with a number. Besides as a convention in Java package naming, the package name is all lower case.

Error on line 63 maybe fixed when you fix the package name. However, this can happen when the class name is not appropriate. If you paste the fully qualified name of the class here, maybe I can help further.

Comment: Thanks A lot this work i got a new error now

Keystore file 'D:\APK GAmes\Dash2D\android\Key1' not found for signing config 'externalOverride'.

if you maybe know what it could be

Comment: Ok i fixed that but now google console gives me this 

Your app has an apk with version code 1 that requests the following permission(s): android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE. Apps using these permissions in an APK are required to have a privacy policy set.

Comment: I think the `signingConfig` is not declared in your `build.gradle` Try fixing that. This link will help you with it. http://www.androiddocs.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html

With `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission, you need to provide a url where your Privacy Policy is declared. Google provides a way for the app users to understand what the developer is doing with their sensitive that.

Answer (score 0):

Last time I tried that I just followed the following thread and it worked perfectly for me:

http://buildbox.com/forum/index.php?threads/android-studio-mini-tutorial.11735/

Try reinstalling android studio and start from the beginning but this time following thaqt thread

Comment: don't post link-only answers. these are useless, esp. when remote site/page is gone.